# Django, how to handle pk and object in one function

Tags: django

How does django handle a parameter which can be primary key or object?

for instance, `MyModel.objects.filter(my_field=id)` works and `MyModel.objects.filter(my_field=my_obj)` also works.

How does django do it? (I'd like to replicate it)

Comment: What you want to replicate... I'm not sure but they will check they type of the keyword argument...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This logic is performed by the [`get_normalized_value`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/e2296e7f0acf9c50868ab997ba565c1f47beb45b/django/db/models/fields/related_lookups.py#L23) method in `django.db.models.fields.related_lookups`:

```
def get_normalized_value(value, lhs):
    from django.db.models import Model
    if isinstance(value, Model):
        value_list = []
        sources = lhs.output_field.get_path_info()[-1].target_fields
        for source in sources:
            while not isinstance(value, source.model) and source.remote_field:
                source = source.remote_field.model._meta.get_field(source.remote_field.field_name)
            try:
                value_list.append(getattr(value, source.attname))
            except AttributeError:
                # A case like Restaurant.objects.filter(place=restaurant_instance),
                # where place is a OneToOneField and the primary key of Restaurant.
                return (value.pk,)
        return tuple(value_list)
    if not isinstance(value, tuple):
        return (value,)
    return value
```

Basically, it checks whether the value is a `Model` instance and if it is, it converts it to the corresponding primary key.